# Deciphering place names in Northern Alsace?

Tags: 18th-century, palaeography, france, place-names

I am having some difficulties with a 1797 marriage record from Birlenbach, Northern Alsace (departement Bas-Rhin), specifically some of the geography. The record is hard to retrieve (all they let me download is a PDF file, which I am having a hard time annotating properly). The original record is at http://archives.bas-rhin.fr/detail-document/ETAT-CIVIL-C42-P1-R47843#visio/page:ETAT-CIVIL-C42-P1-R47843-2924074. I have also captured the screen in order to highlight the place names I am interested in.

[image: screen capture]

The first name I read rather clearly as "Kullendorf", but I cannot find a place with that name. The closest I have come is "Kuhlendorf", about five kilometres southeast of Soultz-sous-forest, 10 km from Birlenbach. The third name could be "Oberbetschdorf", which would be consistent. There is a "Betschdorf" about two kilometres southwest of Kuhlendorf (with a "Niederbetschdorf" immediately to the East). Kuhlendorf is also a part of Betschdorf today.

The second name is the biggest mystery. I read it as "Mordbrunn", but I have doubts about my interpretation, and I have not found anything that fits.

Can anyone shed more light on these three place names for me?

Comment: Could the second name be "_Morsbronn_", rather than "_Mordbrunn_"?

Comment: I now think that the name as written is "Morsbrunn" (the do-hickey on the 'u' is unmistakable), which (probably) corresponds to the current official name of Morsbronn.